# Number of ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Let an ellipse touches y=x at origin and Focii F1, F2 on x=1 , x=-1 respectively .

Then according to me number of such ellipse will only be two .

But in the answer it is given as 3.

[Original source](http://dc.allenbpms.in/testpaper/solution/d9836-18-636288147529098626-018s.gif)

Comment: Excellent question +1.I was not aware of the fact that reflection of a focus on any tangent to an ellipse is collinear with the line joining the other focus and the point of contact of the tangent with the ellipse.

Comment: However since we are getting only two pairs of (a,b) the number of such ellipses should be two.

Comment: Far each $a>0$, let $F_a(1,a)$ there is an **infinite** number of ellipses tangent to line with equation $y=x$ at the origin such that there exist a second foci $F'(-1,b)$ for a certain $b<-1$. The erroneous figure of your document doesn't help...

Comment: @navinstudent have a look at my recent answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2246537).

Comment: Note that the "source" problem also specifies that the semi-major axis $a$ satisfies $9a^2 = 40$.

Comment: @hardmath so whats the use of it

Comment: A constraint of that kind reduces the infinite number of ellipses noted by @JeanMarie to a finite number of solutions.

Comment: @Koolman It's surprising that you just asked "what's the use for it ?" instead of saying first "pardon me, I had forgotten to give this constraint in my question". You ask people to work for you, and you provide them incomplete information. Please, don't do that again.

Comment: @JeanMarie sorry , I will not do it again